# SQL - Find and delete rows which two columns have replicated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table and I want to find and delete rows which two columns have replicated values.

For example:

```
|ID|Name|Address|Birth_Date|
---------------------------
|1 | ab |  abc  |1990-05-24|
|2 | cd |  def  |1980-06-30|
|3 | ab |  xyz  |1990-05-24|
```

Here are two rows with `ID` 1 and 3 that refer to the same person. These rows share same `Name` and same `Birth_Date` values and may differ from one or more attributes, then they are not duplicates.

How can I find and delete these rows preserve only one of these (the first occurrence or the second occurrence)?

I want that the resulting table is the same table with only one occurrence of those rows preserved:

```
|ID|Name|Address|Birth_Date|
---------------------------
|1 | ab |  abc  |1990-05-24|
|2 | cd |  def  |1980-06-30|
```

Comment: id 0 ? very uncommon to see id 0 in SQL?   Is this deletion a one time deal?

Comment: They are not duplicate rows, but they differ from one or more attributes

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as here the last one should be kept (not required in the previous question) : 
First part is to get the old id for duplicates:
`SELECT o.id FROM (SELECT id, name, Birth_Date FROM table) o INNER JOIN (SELECT id, name, Birth_Date FROM table) n WHERE o.name = n.name AND o.Birth_Date = n.Birth_Date and o.id<n.id`
use that to delete:
`DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT o.id FROM (SELECT id, name, Birth_Date FROM table) o INNER JOIN (SELECT id, name, Birth_Date FROM table) n WHERE o.name = n.name AND o.Birth_Date = n.Birth_Date and o.id<n.id)`

Comment: Also test FIRST if the first query (`SELECT o.id FROM (SELECT id, name, Birth_Date FROM table) o INNER JOIN (SELECT id, name, Birth_Date FROM table) n WHERE o.name = n.name AND o.Birth_Date = n.Birth_Date and o.id<n.id`) returns the right IDs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like below

```
delete  from table_name where (id,name) in (

select id,name from (
select max(id) as id, name,Birth_Date,count(*) as cnt
from table_name group by name,Birth_Date
) a where cnt>1
```

)

Comment: this will only delete one row -- what if there is more than one?

Comment: @Hogan op wants to delete one row

Comment: he said in the question "find and delete rows ..." that sounds like plural to me.

Comment: I can try this command while no rows are deleted. However, it works